# check for already registered with this app in facebook login in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api, fbsdk

I am integrating FB in my app for login & signup purpose in my iOS app..

While i signup with fb from app, i want to know the user has `already registered with fb` for that app or not,

if he is already registered 
then i want to perform `login actions`

otherwise `signup actions`..!!

```
- (void)  loginButton:(FBSDKLoginButton *)loginButton
    didCompleteWithResult:(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *)result
                error:(NSError *)error{

    FBSDKGraphRequest *request = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc]
                                  initWithGraphPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%@",result.token.userID]
                                  parameters:@{ @"fields" : @"id, name, email, first_name, hometown, last_name, location" }
                                  HTTPMethod:@"GET"];
    [request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
        [self handleRequestCompletionWithResult:result error:error];
    }];
}


- (void)handleRequestCompletionWithResult:(id)result error:(NSError *)error
    {
    NSString *title = nil;
    NSString *message = nil;
    if (error) {
        title = @"Graph Request Fail";
        message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Graph API request failed with error:\n %@", error];
    } else {
        title = @"Graph Request Success";
        message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Graph API request success with result:\n %@", result];
        if(already registered user) {
             //perform login for my app
        } else  {
             //perform signup action for my app
        }
    }
    NSLog(@"%@",message);
}
```

Is there any way to achieve it?

Comment: aren't you using the backend? at the end of facebook request, the information you achieved, you have to send those information to backend through web-service and backend will handle it that it's registration or login. backend can send you the information that users signed up or logged in.

Comment: if still in-case you want to keep a track that facebook user signup or logged in, then you can create a local database and store the id's of those logged in user. by facebook request you will get facebook id, compares it to your local database stored facebook id's. if it's present then it's a login or register it.

Comment: yes, i can manage it on backend.. but is there any solution by fbsdk for this?

Comment: This happens automatically, i mean you add a FSDKLoginButton, and if the user has already authorised then well and good, else the login page opens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did integrate the FBSDK in one of my apps recently, and this is what i did to check if the user is already authorised.

```
if ([FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]) {
//perform login for your app
}
else {
// perform signup action for your app
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: The presence of an access token check if the user is already logged in. It does not tell you if the user has authorized the app. As a matter of fact, the user could have already authorized the app, but have a nil token if he is logged out.